# A pleasant police presence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm translating an English travel guide of Edinburgh and having some questions over a sentence.
Here's the context: "A few steps downhill, at #188 (on the right), is the Police Information Center. This place provides a pleasant police presence (say that three times) and a little local law-and-order history to boot."

My questions is, does "a pleasant police presence" here mean "adequate police personnel"?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a Scottish travel guide?

Answer (score 1):

It is a joke, understandable to most Scots and a lot of UK people. Traditionally British police used a number of tests to see if a person was drunk (e.g. walk a straight line, touch their nose with their eyes shut, etc). One of these is to say "The Leith Police dismisseth us" a number of times without slurring any words. Leith is the port district of Edinburgh. "A pleasant police presence" is similar to the old police test. That's the joke. I would not bother translating it. I suggest translating "This place provides some local law-and-order history."

Note that in the UK, we spell 'Centre' like this. As 'Police Information Centre' is a proper noun it should be spelt so. Also we don't usually write numbers with a hash sign ('#').

Comment: While the question may not be legit (seems lifted from [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-pleasant-police-presence.3775178/) by an imposter in a case of mass fraud), this is a really good answer. Too good to delete. +1